# read a text file, make every character lowercase and store it in an array

Tags: c

I would like to read in a text file and store the characters in an array. But the stored characters all have to be lower cased and keep a running count of the number of words. We can assume that we will use no more that the first 5000 words in the test and no more than the first 15 characters in a word. How would I fix make the each character into lower case.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int main()
    {
           FILE *inFile;
           char userInputFileName[100];
           char *line = malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
           int count = 0;
           char *token;
           char delim[] = " ,.!;:\n";
           char *eachWord;

           printf("Please enter the name of the text file \n");
           scanf("%s", &userInputFileName);
           inFile = fopen(userInputFileName, "r");

           if(inFile == NULL)
           {
                 fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file \n");
                 exit(1);
            }

          while(fgets(line, sizeof(line),inFile)
          {
              printf("%s\n", line); 
              char newWord[5000];

                   while((eachWord = strtok(token, delim)) != NULL)
                   {
                        strcpy(newWord[count], eachWord);
                   }
              count++;
         }
}
```

Comment: Your program doesn't compile.

Comment: I just made an edit to your program in order to compile. You had forgotten a parenthesis.

Comment: do you have to store the white characters (space, new line) as well?

Comment: The C standard library have many [functions dealing with strings and characters](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte), including a couple for [character manipulation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte#Character_manipulation) that might come in handy here.

Comment: Use **tolower(p++);** where **p** is a pointer pointing to the beginning of a string.  **while(tolower(p++));** will automatically terminate on reaching the null byte at the end of a well-formed string. You might need to add a null byte if working with a general array of chars, or the output of some string functions.

Comment: By the way, `fgets(line, sizeof(line),inFile)` will *not* read as many characters as you expect. Instead of allocating `line` dynamically try making it a normal array.

Comment: By doing an OR bitwise(  |  ) with 32 you will assure that the characters remain lowercase if they're in the standard ascii table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `while` loop has some thought errors. I'll outline them to you but won't fix them so you can fix them and learn.

You write `while(fgets(line, sizeof(line),...` but that will read only 4 or 8 characters. Why? Read about `sizeof` and then look at what you are asking the size of.

In the while loop you say `char newWord[5000]`. That means you are allocating one array of 5000 characters. But in your problem statement you say "*...5000 words in the test and no more than the first 15 characters*". So there is a thought error and you would need an array for 5000 words of *15 characters each*.

But, you are declaring this array in the loop, meaning it will be destroyed at the bottom of the while loop and recreated at the top. So you loose the word(s) just read and stored. You should allocate the array where it will not be destroyed and recreated with every iteration.

In tyour `strcpy` you do not make sure that only the first 15 characters (as per your problem statement) are copied. Use the right copy function to do that. And don't forget to terminate the copied characters.

And then after the `while strtok...` you increment count. That does not seem the right place to count the number of words.

Go back to the drawing board...